# Can't center circular animation with CSS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have an app running at this URL:

https://sentify-kth.herokuapp.com/my-searches

As you can see, there is a circular loading animation in the table. I want to place this animation in the middle of the table body, like this (imagine that it's in the center and not slightly to the right):

[image]

I can't get this to work. My attempt has been to style the element with `class=progress`. I've tried `width:100%; margin:auto`. I've also tried `text-align:center`. That didn't work either. I don't know what else to try.

How can I center the circular animation?

The React code:

```
  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    const { data, selected, rowsPerPage, page } = this.state;
    let tableBody;
    let emptyRows;
    switch(this.state.status){
      case "LOADING":
        tableBody = <CircularIndeterminate/>;
        emptyRows = undefined;
        break;
      case "LOADED":
        tableBody = <CircularIndeterminate/>;
        break;
    }

    return (
      <Paper className={classes.root}>
        <EnhancedTableToolbar
            numSelected={selected.length}
            handleClickDeleteBtn={this.handleClickDeleteBtn}
            open={this.state.open}
            handleCloseModal={this.handleCloseModal}
            handleConfirm={this.handleConfirm}
            handleCancel={this.handleCancel}
        />
        <div className={classes.tableWrapper}>
          <Table className={classes.table}>
            <EnhancedTableHead
              numSelected={selected.length}
              onSelectAllClick={this.handleSelectAllClick}
              rowCount={data === null || data === undefined ? -1 : (data.length || -1)}
            />
            <TableBody>
              {tableBody}
              {emptyRows > 0 && (
                <TableRow style={{ height: 49 * emptyRows }}>
                  <TableCell colSpan={6} />
                </TableRow>
              )}
            </TableBody>
          </Table>
        </div>
        <TablePagination
          component="div"
          count={data === null || data === undefined ? 0 : data.length || 0}
          rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
          page={page}
          backIconButtonProps={{
            'aria-label': 'Previous Page',
          }}
          nextIconButtonProps={{
            'aria-label': 'Next Page',
          }}
          onChangePage={this.handleChangePage}
          onChangeRowsPerPage={this.handleChangeRowsPerPage}
        />
      </Paper>
    );
  }
}
```

CircularIndeterminate.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from 'material-ui/styles';
import { CircularProgress } from 'material-ui/Progress';

const styles = theme => ({
  progress: {
    margin: theme.spacing.unit * 2,
  },
});

function CircularIndeterminate(props) {
  const { classes } = props;
  return (
    <div className="progress">
      <CircularProgress className={classes.progress} size={100} thickness={4}/>
    </div>
  );
}

CircularIndeterminate.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(CircularIndeterminate);
```

Comment: try with `display:flex`, `justify-content: center` and `align-items: center` to parent of `CircularProgress`

Comment: First off your markup on the page linked is invalid. You can't just jam a `div` tag into a `tbody` without the row `tr` and cell `td` wrapping it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I solved it (there was an answer saying pretty much the same thing, but it was removed for an unknown reason):

1. Put the circle in a `tr` and `td` element
2. Set `colspan=6` on the `td` element
3. Set `text-align:center` for the .progress element.

Code:

```
tableBody = (
          <tr>
            <td colspan="6">
              <CircularIndeterminate/>
            </td>
          </tr>
          );
```

css:

```
.progress{
    text-align:center
}
```